# Next.js styling only works for first style

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use Next.js styling as per the docs but the current code only works for the background colour, but does not work for the test class on the image. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <div className="header-bg">
    <Container className="pt-5 pb-5">
      <Row className="align-items-center">
        <Col>
          <h1>Welcome to the home page. Here is some text</h1>
          <p>Here is some paragraph text</p>
          <Button variant="info">Learn More</Button>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Image src="chair.png" className="test" />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
    <style jsx>{`
      .header-bg {
        background: grey;
      }
      .test {
        max-width: 15px;
      }
    `}</style>
  </div>
```

Comment: what's your `Image` component? does it expect the `className`?

Comment: I have found that using next.js jsx styles doesn't work with React Bootstrap. Well, maybe it does but I don't know how to get it to work. For example it works if I type out the full bootstrap class name in a div like: `<div className="btn">` but it won't work if I use <Button/>